# How to retain table data on input field on clicking a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
<script>
function post()
{

 if(document.getElementById("stdName").value == "select"){
  alert("select a student name")
  return false;

}
</script>
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<th>id</th>
<th>name</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" id="id1" name="id1"></td>
<td><select id="stdName" name="stdName">
 <option>select</option>
 <option>a</option>
 <option>b</option>
 <option>c</option>
  </select>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<button id="prerec" onclick="return post()">GetRecord</button>
```

I have a table in which on entering a student name and clicking a button(not submit button), i will be able to see the previous records of that particular student. But once after getting the previous record, the name in the input field disappear which should not happen. How can i retain this name ?

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: you can store the input in a variable, upon clicking the button you can then load in the variable so that it remains there.